# How do I stop my external hard drive from using all my RAM?

Tags: macos, time-machine, hard-drive, memory, external-disk

I'm running OSX Mavericks, and have an external 500Gb HD connected via firewire.

I have 24GB's of RAM, and fairly often my RAM usage will spike to 23.95 GBs in use and literally leave me with only 50 MB of RAM, or less, usable.

I know it's my external drive because when I eject it the memory usage goes back to normal, which is about 5GB used.

How do I stop the drive from using so much memory?

Comment: Are there any special processes/applications accessing the external drive?

Comment: And how do you see it is using the memory? what do you mean by usable memory? As memory is used for caching it is probably the best use to have very low free memory, what matters is does the OS need to swap

Answer (score 1):

The external drive by itself won't use RAM. Check the processes that are running in Activity Monitor — you can sort by RAM usage.

[image]

Comment: @zm15 Does it still use RAM in a new user account? In safe mode (⇧-boot)?

Comment: yes, i have checked the processes and nothing major there. The largest by a fair amount is kernel_task with 1.37 GB.

I'm guessing it's a process of some kind i just don't know what. 

Still uses RAM in safe mode as well.

!(http://cl.ly/image/3w0T3f3M0I1l/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-18%20at%201.34.17%20PM.png).